# Masking Range-Enabled Feature Layers

Tags: arcgis-pro, feature-layer, masking

Is there a way to mask features that have been range-enabled?

I have a range enabled polygon feature of different project boundaries. I am using this range to show/unshow features in bookmarks similar to this article.
https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/mapping/changing-data-in-a-map-series-using-range-and-bookmarks/

What I would like to do is mask an underlying feature layer so that only the current ranged polgyon masks it rather than the entire project boundary feature masking the underlying layer.

[image: Mask Area outside ranged polygon]